# Parsing string to Datetime object

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I need to parse string from datapicker to a DataTime object and save in Sqlite db
ex: "20/03/2012"

`"20/03/2012".to_datetime` -  don't work

Quetion closed `DateTime.parse("12/12/2012")` - helped!
Just in case if anybody runs in such issue as I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
date_time = "20/03/2012"
p DateTime.strptime(date_time, "%d/%m/%Y")
# => #<DateTime: 2012-03-20T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456007j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):004:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> DateTime.parse("20/03/2012")
=> #<DateTime: 2012-03-20T00:00:00+00:00 (4912013/2,0/1,2299161)>
```

Comment: +1, thanks! Was trying all kinds of methods to do something so simple